# Handling Custom Error

Tags: hardhat, custom-errors

Why it doesn't work when I use...

```
$ yarn hardhat --verison 2.10.2
```

```
await expect(fundMeConnectedContract.withdraw()
            ).to.be.revertedWith(
                "FundMe__NotOwner"
            )
```

but this worked

```
await expect(fundMeConnectedContract.withdraw()
            ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(
                fundMeConnectedContract,
                "FundMe__NotOwner"
            )
```

Has the hardhat custom error handling changed since May this year..??

Comment: See the latest answers in this discussion on GitHub: [Custom errors not picked up by Hardhat Network when using external Hardhat artifact](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/1618).

Answer (score 0):

the former is matching against the revert message.

e.g.

```
.to.be.revertedWith("go away")
```

would work with this code

```
require(msg.sender == owner,"go away");
```

the latter is just matching against the custom error

Answer (score 0):

```js
    await expect(fundMeConnectedContract.withdraw()).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(fundMe, "FundMe__NotOwner")
```

Hey , buddy if you follow exactly the tutorial. try `revertedWithCustomError`
and add `fundMe, "FundMe__NotOwner"`.

> Line explanation :
>
> - `fundMe` will be your deployed contract
> - `FundMe__NotOwner` the custom error from `fundMe.sol`

*Do also check if you using single or double underscore* for `FundMe__NotOwner` in `fundMe.sol`

I hope this would help if you still not found out the solution

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got an Answer already, if not just try to delete the custom error passed to revertedWithCustomError and write it down yourself. I copie-pasted it and it could not recognise as defined custom-Error in the contract.